# some files not opening properly on hosting server awardspace

Tags: web, upload, jpeg

I've uploaded files for my website from my home test server to my hosting account on awardspace.
It is weird that some pictures work when directlinking but others don't and I don't get why

It are jpg files, and it's in a particular folder /images
and even weirder is that with some jpg files in that folder direct linking works, but with other jpgs it doesn't. I get an 403 error, while the file is there. I can see it with filezilla....

So what is wrong? on the home test server direct linking works.

EDIT: I'm guessing it has something to do with their forbidden words list. Although it's odd as pictures do not contain text?! I certainly hope they don't enforce the list on a paid hosting account as I already ordered one...

Comment: 403 is a permissions error. Do the files that don't work have different permission settings from those that do work?

Comment: Sounds like a user permissions problem. Were all the files uploaded using the same FTP account? Has any PHP uploading been in play?

Comment: yes, I also work with php on the server and I used the same FTP account. i just found out even an html file in another folder isn't working: 403 as well

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Awardspace very recently, and used core-ftp lite ftp program to easily change permissions to read, write and execute. It all works fine with me.